# sbt testQuick does not rerun on transitive dependent code changes

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm experimenting with testQuick for TDD but have come across the following issue. I have reduced it to a minimal nonsensical example. Perhaps my setup is wrong. Thanks for looking into it.

I have 3 scala projects:

- tests
- foo
- bar

tests depends on foo which depends on bar. When I change code in foo, the source is recompiled and the test is rerun. However, when I change code in bar (setting the value to false), the source is only recompiled and the test is ***not*** rerun. The output is simply as follows:

```
[info] 1. Monitoring source files for testquick/tests/Test/testQuick...
[info]    Press <enter> to interrupt or '?' for more options.
[info] Build triggered by <shortened>/bar/src/main/scala/Bar.scala. Running 'tests/Test/testQuick'.
[info] compiling 1 Scala source to <shortened>/bar/target/scala-3.2.2/classes ...
[info] Passed: Total 0, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 0
[info] No tests to run for tests / Test / testQuick
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed May 19, 2023, 11:18:15 PM
[info] 2. Monitoring source files for testquick/tests/Test/testQuick...
[info]    Press <enter> to interrupt or '?' for more options.
```

The example was done with sbt version 1.8.3 and command:
`sbt "~tests/Test/testQuick"`

build.sbt:

```
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "3.2.2"

lazy val tests = project.dependsOn(foo).settings(
  libraryDependencies += "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.2.16",
  libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.16" % "test"
)
lazy val foo = project.dependsOn(bar)
lazy val bar = project
```

tests/src/test/scala/TestSpec.scala:

```
import org.scalatest.*
import flatspec.*

class TestSpec extends AnyFlatSpec {
  "Foo" should "be true" in {
    assert(Foo.doFoo())
  }
}
```

foo/src/main/scala/Foo.scala:

```
object Foo {
  def doFoo(): Boolean = Bar.doBar()
}
```

bar/src/main/scala/Bar.scala:

```
object Bar {
  def doBar(): Boolean = true
}
```

Comment: Maybe consider opening an issue at SBT project with your minimal reproduction case.

Comment: Hi there and thanks for your response. I was going to do that, but then read in sbt's support.md that they prefer questions asked here. If one is 90% sure that it is a bug, an issue is preferred. The transitive dependency seems fundamental to me that it should work and it must be my approach rather than a bug :)